# Why would using Caliburn Action inside a Blend KeyTrigger break my View?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro, wpf-4.0

Caliburn Micro 2.0.2 and WPF 4 and .NET 4.5.

Using a very simple view and a very simple viewmodel to demonstrate, I notice that if I have a Caliburn Action inside a KeyTrigger, my View is not activated properly. When I say 'properly' I mean that if I look at it in Snoop, the whole UserControl is disabled. If I change it to a Window and open it as Window rather than an embedded control, Snoop cannot even find that Window and the control remains disabled.

Here is my ViewModel:

```
using System.Windows.Input;
using Caliburn.Micro;

namespace PlainSailTech.ViewModels.Admin
{
    public class SystemConfigurationViewModel : Screen
    {
        private bool canShowDevLinks;

        public bool CanShowDevLinks
        {
            get { return canShowDevLinks; }
            set
            {
                if (value.Equals(canShowDevLinks)) return;
                canShowDevLinks = value;
            }
        }

        public void ShowDevLinks(KeyEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args != null)
                args.Handled = true;
            CanShowDevLinks = !CanShowDevLinks;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="PlainSailTech.Bookkeeping.Ui.Views.Admin.SystemConfigurationView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
         xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
         xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Title="Caliburn Action test"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ei:KeyTrigger Modifiers="Ctrl" Key="D" FiredOn="KeyUp" ActiveOnFocus="True">
        <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="ShowDevLinks">
            <cal:Parameter Value="$eventArgs" />
        </cal:ActionMessage>
    </ei:KeyTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
<Grid>
    <Grid Width="Auto">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="#FFFBFBFB" Visibility="{Binding CanShowDevLinks, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisible}}">
            <TextBlock Text="Dev links here" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Top" IsReadOnly="False" IsEnabled="True" Width="150" Height="30">
                <TextBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="Enabled"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="Disabled"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBox.Style>
            </TextBox>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Notice that the TextBox is set to enabled but the whole control is being disabled. You can see this from this screen shot:

[image: Disabled Window]

However, if I simply remove the Caliburn Action, everything is good again:

```
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ei:KeyTrigger Modifiers="Ctrl" Key="D" FiredOn="KeyUp" ActiveOnFocus="True">
    </ei:KeyTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

[image: Good window without Caliburn Action]

A few possible clues. The problem goes away if:

If I replace the Caliburn Action with:

```
 <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" PropertyName="CanShowDevLinks" Value="True">
```

Or my ViewModel does not inherit from Screen or PropertyChangedBase.

If I override OnViewAttached and wire up a handler for EnableChanged, I can see the IsEnabled being set to false after the View is attached.

So it seems like an interaction between whatever is happening in the Screen/PropertyChangedBase base class and the wiring up of the Action.

Answer (score 0):

Okay - the answer to this question is the person who asked it is an idiot. I have a guard property that has the name of the action's method. Because the KeyTrigger is below the UserControl, it is disabling the whole thing. Arghhh...

I knew that a guard property applied when you named a button, for example, but I didn't realise that it applied to any UI element that has an action attached to it. You live and learn, occasionally.